# in JavaScript . I Got stuck in this issue. i am planing to do slide page when click on other page link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i got stuck in slide page. when sliding page url and page is not changing. but function is working.

this is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#body").css("display", "none");

        $("#body").slideToggle(200);

        $("a.transition").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("#body").addClass('bounceOutLeft');
            $("#body").slide(100, redirectPage);

        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise about your problem? Are you sure you mean $("#body") and not $("body")?

Comment: $("body")  this is also okay.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#body").css("display", "none");

        $("#body").slideToggle(200);

        $("a.transition").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("#body").addClass('bounceOutLeft');
            $("#body").slide(100, redirectPage);

        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }

    });                                                                                                                  In this page redirectPage not working

Comment: The redirectPage Not working

Comment: and Its not Just div its full page

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you check whether redirectPage is actually called? debug the code or output something to the console or alert() to check.

Comment: Thats cool. when i add alert() in script Its working fine. But when i remove the alert() its not working